# Weird behaviour of PHP SOAP Webservice on Ubuntu and apache2

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php

We got a SOAP Webservice written in PHP. We also got PHPUnit Tests for this Webservice. Till last week we used Xampp on Ubuntu 12.04.4. Using Xampp the Webservice worked fine. Then last week we decided to use lamp instead. We removed Xampp and installed lamp:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql mysql-server
```

Since then my SOAP Webservice behaves very strange! Every time i execute the same PHPUnit Tests I'm getting different results. But we got this Problem only on my computer.

We tried to execute the tests on another computer, calling my SOAP Webservice - same result.
I removed and installed lamp a couple of times, without any success.

- Does anyone have any idea, what the problem could be?
- If you need any further information or config files etc. please tell me.

Comment: You should tell what results you get and what you expect to get. Also you should provide error messages from your PHPUnit Tests. And pls. have a look at /var/log/apache2/yourvhost-access/error.log

Comment: I just noticed that I don't get back anything, if a test fails. (We expect a SOAP fault, thats why i didnt notice that earlier).

Comment: So the Soap-Server sometimes gives back an empty response. In this case the request dose not even get processed (I know that, course i don't see them in the server logs).

Comment: there is nothing in the error.log ...

Comment: and there are also no errors in the PHPUnit Test, since there is no actual error.

Answer (score 0):

> **Solved!**
>
> Solution: in the Soap Webservice we were using PHP classes, PHP casted
>   the webservice request (stdClass Object) to our custom classes. We
>   never thought that might be a problem, course there where no errors
>   thrown. But anyway, after we manually converted the stdClass objects
>   in our custom objects, everything seems to work as expected. We still
>   have no clue why it worked on one machine, and not on the other.
>   Thanks for your Help!

-- originally posted in question by OP.